# SQL Script for Bulk Deletion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to write a SQL Script to bulk delete rows in a table with input from a Text File. I am just getting into SQL Scripting.

Backstory: Someone in my previous role setup a table without a primary key and a program was designed to insert data into the table.  However, the program would never check for duplicate entries first and just go ahead and do the insert.

I am attempting to clean-up the database.

First, I have run a query to see just how many rows are duplicates.  There are roughly ~7,000 therefore, there is no way I am going to delete them one query at a time.  [ID] should have been setup as a Primary Key.

Query to determine duplicates

```
SELECT [ID] FROM [testing].[dbo].[testingtable]
GROUP BY [ID]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I can delete the duplicate rows by using the following query on an individual ID:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
DELETE FROM [testing].[dbo].[testingtable]
WHERE [ID] = SomeNumber
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

I have a text file of all of the duplicate ID number entries, however, is there a bulk delete script that I can create so that I can feed in all of the ID duplicate numbers from the text file? Or is there a more efficient way.  Please point me in the direction.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove a very high percentage of rows...

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... 
INTO #Holdingtable
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ..opposite condition..

TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable

INSERT MyTable (col1, col2, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, ... 
FROM #Holdingtable
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have (or need) a text file of all duplicate IDs.

*There are roughly ~7,000 therefore, there is no way I am going to delete them one query at a time*
 Of course there is a way to delete them, here we go:

If you just want to remove duplicates from your table, use this code:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [ID]
         ,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [ID])
   FROM [testing].[dbo].[testingtable]
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```